# "Gave up waiting for the root" error during boot

Tags: boot, grub2, root, initramfs

I have installed UBUNTU 14.04 on my UEFI based system in which Windows 8 was pre-installed recently, and I face the following problem whenever I boot from the grub2 boot menu.

```
Gave up waiting for root device.  Common problems:
  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
  ALERT!  /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXXXXXXXXXXX does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!


BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built in commands.
```

If I press exit and then hit enter it boots successfully without any problem. I did try boot repair to fix it and this is what I got.

[Boot repair output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8907247/)

Please help me how to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also occurred same problem but I can solve it using following link

http://blog.wittchen.biz.pl/ubuntu-system-boot-problem/

**Attempt #1**

First, I tried to change rootdelay as error message said. I opened file /etc/default/grub
I found there the following line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
and changed it to:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rootdelay=90 quiet splash"
rootdelay became longer, but unfortunately it didn’t fix the problem in my case.

**Attempt #2**

I edited /etc/fstab file. I executed the following command in terminal: sudo gedit /etc/fstab and edited fstab file in gedit. In the beginning my file looked like that:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=96889309-5f73-4688-8354-e64cd1bb158f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=480cc3f7-a39d-4d0f-93d5-49fc8df1a392 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Then, I commented one line and added another one describing /dev/sda1 disk device. Now, my file looks as follows:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=/dev/sda1  /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# UUID=96889309-5f73-4688-8354-e64cd1bb158f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=480cc3f7-a39d-4d0f-93d5-49fc8df1a392 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Problem still existed, so I tried another attempt to solve it.

**Attempt #3**

I opened terminal and typed the following command:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

and then I typed another command to update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

After all of this, I rebooted computer and finally, error disappeared and problem was fixed!